# Google Sheets, how to sumif value in another row is a date?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table of data that contains labels, and the date that the values next to those labels are summed in one row, and the data itself in subsequent rows like this:

```
A             B         C
SM         10,291     $3.09
RCOM        5,171    $11.96
ED          4,752     $5.70
RS         31,748    $27.41
AO         50,745     $5.41
06/25/16  102,707    $53.57
```

I would like to have a master "total" cell that sums only the cells that contain totals.  So in English - "Sum B if A is not text".

I found the `isnontext()` function, and I know about `sumif()`, but I can't quite figure out how to make this work.  Hopefully that's clear and someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, the real data is many hundreds of rows long and contains summaries every few rows, so I need a formula that can accommodate that

Comment: Aha, I hadn't considered that sheets might see any alpha value as being less than one. I will be back at my desk later and will give this a try…

Comment: Hah that was simple.  Worked like a charm... feel free to submit it as an answer if you wish and I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems:

```
=sumif(A:A,">1",B:B)
```

was adequate. There is no numeric value for text entries in a formula such as above, so they are ignored and only all the numeric ones need be 'captured', if the alternative to Text is only Date.

Comment: This was perfect, I just didn't realize Sheets would simply ignore non-numeric values.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Aha... good to know as well!